# Rest API URL Query

Tags: soql, url, c#

I have an external application and I am trying to pass through a value using the Rest API URL queries, everything on it works, but when I try to add this one field (it is not custom), it sends me a 400 Bad Request.

The censored's are just more fields, I can't show due to compliance. If I were to remove IsAllDayEvent, it works, once I add it, the 400 appears again, and I double checked with Workbench to make sure I am using the right name. the {}'s are variables with values being passed.

```
$"{{\"censored\":\"{censored}\", \"IsAllDayEvent\":\"{isAllDayEvent}\", \"censored\":\"{censored}\", \"censored\":\"{censored}\", \"censored\":\"{censored}\", \"censored\":\"censored\", \"censored\":\"{censored}\", \"censored\":\"{censored}\"}}";
```

Answer (score 2):

It's expecting a Boolean value, not a String, as this is a Checkbox field. Remove the quotes.

```
$"{... \"IsAllDayEvent\":{isAllDayEvent}, ...}";
```

For future reference, this is also true for number fields, such as currency.

Comment: Thank you, it didn't solve my problem, but you are right, I was doing it the wrong way. But the reason it is throwing a 400, is because in salesforce, if you select "All Day Event" then you can't have an enddatetime or startdatetime, which i had censored out. I am trying to send all day event AND the time's up. I will have to do some logic on my end to sort it out, but thanks!

Comment: @CodyB I'm just glad I could help point you in the right direction.

Comment: I put the logic in for it and the values being passed into it are correct, it is still not liking what I am trying to send. Im quite lost because this is a Salesforce issue that I cannot resolve. I have tried sending it as a boolean and as a string, even with different datetime formats.

Comment: @CodyB Check your "field level security" on the field. I found out it was disabled in my org, and that may be your problem to. Go to Setup > Object Manager > Event > Fields > All Day Event, and check the Field Level Security. You can't use the field if it is not Visible.

Comment: @CodyB Here's an example I used in workbench, so I know it works: `{ "subject": "Demo", "isAllDayEvent": true, "activityDate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" }`

Comment: Yea, i just tested it. I know EXACTLY what I was doing wrong.... True needs to be ALL lower case. I've converted it to lowercase and it works in my testing grounds. However I have the SAME exact setup in my actual project, and the bool being passed to it was lowercase, however, the variable the string is assigned to makes it "True" again. I don't know if this is a bug or me not knowing... here is some code ->  https://prnt.sc/r850pq   .. https://prnt.sc/r850yh

Comment: @CodyB What language is that? Maybe I can help you out, I'm a bit of a jack-of-all-trades in coding.

Comment: It is c#, I am working on a project right now at work haha. But I did get that issue fixed, thank god it was not what I was expecting it to be. I basically just had to go do a .ToString().ToLower() on the exact instance before it was compiled into the variable. so basically ``\"IsAllDayEvent\":\"{isAllDayEvent.ToString().ToLower()}\",``